# Pipeline hangs with only one agent

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to configure a pipeline with these steps:

- Build
- Copy artifacts
- Integration test

I want them to be executed in this specific order on the same agent.

My setup is the server and one agent.

If I do this configuration

```
pipeline {
    agent ???
    options {
        copyArtifactPermission(...);
    }
    
    stages
    {
        stage('BuildStage')
        {
            agent {label 'agent1'}
            steps
            {
                build( [...] )
            }
        }
        stage('Copy artifacts')
        {
            agent {label 'agent1'}
            steps
            {
                copyArtifacts ...
            }
        }
        stage('Integration Test')
        {
            agent {label 'agent1'}
            steps
            {
                build( [...] )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that the steps are not scheduled because the master node is busy executing the pipeline.

I'm thinking that I should force the master to execute the pipeline (hence the agent ???) and each stage on the agent?

I can get it to work by adding 'wait:false' to each step, but then I'm not sure the order is kept?

I have also set number of executors to 2, but it doesn't seem to solve the problem.

I'm coming from TeamCity, so maybe I've just misunderstood something basic about Jenkins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the steps are meant to be run in the same agent, you can set it only once:

```js
pipeline {
  agent { label 'agent1' }
  ...
  // Remove all other 'agent'
}
```

Don`t worry about the stages order (quote from https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#sequential-stages)

> Stages in Declarative Pipeline may have a stages section containing a
> list of nested stages to be run in sequential order.